# how to call an activity when getting incoming call.

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-input-method

Hi all i want to invoke a my own activity over the default incoming call activity.. i have done this with using broadcast receivers i am invoking my activity when getting incoming call. but it is working fine for first time from second time when i get incoming call then default incoming call activity is coming over my activity . i don't know what is the problem can any one please help me ..

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.satish.service"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver
        android:name="MyCallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="10">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >

            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="TestReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="10">
            <action android:name="jason.wei.custom.intent.action.TEST" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="CallActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000"></intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Java Code:

```
public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
 public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "jason.wei.custom.intent.action.TEST";
Context context = null;
 private static final String TAG = "Phone call";



public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.w("DEBUG", state);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
                    context.sendBroadcast(i);

        }
    }
}
}


public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(MyCallReceiver.CUSTOM_INTENT)) {
        System.out.println("GOT THE INTENT");
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, CallActivity.class)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    }
}
}

public class CallActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private ITelephony telephonyService;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.call)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.end)).setOnClickListener(this);
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  

      try {
           Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
           Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
           m.setAccessible(true);
           telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
          } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.call:

        telephonyService.answerRingingCall();
        break;

    case R.id.end:
        telephonyService.endCall();
        finish();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi got sloved this issue .. thanks for supporting me..

Comment: I created a thread to call my activity and in that i wrote one statement before that start activity that is sleep for 500ms . that is my solutions... if any one is not under statd then ask me i will post code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the full code was i posted aboove just replace the the below code

```
public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getAction().equals(MyCallReceiver.CUSTOM_INTENT)) {
    System.out.println("GOT THE INTENT");
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, CallActivity.class)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
}
}
 }
```

with the below code

```
 public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(MyCallReceiver.CUSTOM_TEST_INTENT)) {
        System.out.println("GOT THE INTENT");
        final String mobileNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("number");
        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            private int sleepTime = 400;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                try {
                    int wait_Time = 0;

                    while (wait_Time < sleepTime ) {
                        sleep(100);
                        wait_Time += 100;
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Error Occured Because:" + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                finally {

                }

                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, CallActivity.class).putExtra("number", mobileNumber)
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
            }
        };
        thread.run();
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Is there any chance that this topic will be clarified?
Public answer is not enough, public clear answer is way to go.. ;)

Comment: The above answer is very clear ... if you want i will post complete code... I am very busy with my project thats why i am late. if any one want complete source code please ask i will send to you..

Comment: Hi Pandu, I want the same. When there is an incoming call i want to show an activity. I tried your code but I failed to open my activity can you share complete code?

Comment: @pandu hi, thanks for the above cod, but this is not working, still getting incoming call.

Comment: @pandu pls you have solution then pls help me.

Comment: @pandu please upload the code on dropbox and share the link.desperately need it.Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I created a thread to call my activity and in that i wrote one statement before that start activity that is sleep for 500ms . that is my solutions... if any one is not under statd then ask me i will post code here.

Comment: Please find the below answer if it is helpfull for you then select as answer.