# Stop launching of call Receive screen and respond by own Activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to stop launching of call receive screen (default, as usual when call comes) when any incoming call occurs. Instead of that I want to launch my own Activity to respond.

Comment: Go with this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069667/how-to-call-an-activity-when-getting-incoming-call

Comment: it was a good link, but my problem is i want to stop default one.

Comment: i got resolved this problem with an alternative solution and posting the answer for this question with my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first make a subclass of BroadcastReceiver
`public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {`

add it in manifest.xml file
`<receiver android:name="com.myapp.calldropper.CallReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

in onReceive start another Activity Screen upon the default

```
Intent callRejectIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
callRejectIntent.putExtra("MOBILE_NUMBER", mobNum);
callRejectIntent.putExtra("REJECT_COUNT", rejectCount);
callRejectIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(callRejectIntent);
```

your Activity will launch upon the default one. now you can responde the incomming call from your activity, you can Reject call.
for that make a seperate package named `com.android.internal.telephony` and in this create a simple text file named `ITelephony.aidl`. this file will contain

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;
import android.os.Bundle;
interface ITelephony {
    boolean endCall();
    void dial(String number);
    void answerRingingCall();
}
```

add code below in onCreate

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        // "cheat" with Java reflection to gain access to TelephonyManager's ITelephony getter
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

now you can reject the call by calling below function

```
private void ignoreCall() {
    try {
        // telephonyService.silenceRinger();
        telephonyService.endCall();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    finish();
}
```